# docker-compose: execute database scripts

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I am setting up a local mssql database using docker-compose and a dockerfile.

I was able to use the example here:

```
https://github.com/mcmoe/mssqldocker
```

which executes a database script to create the database upon startup. I am now running a couple of sql scripts to setup the database.

So I can run:

```
docker-compose build
```

then...

```
docker-compose up
```

And docker will start mssql and run the scripts to create my database, schemas with tables, views and pre-populated data.

However, if I run:

```
docker-compose stop
```

then run:

```
docker-compose up
```

It tries to run all the scripts *again* which is not good (lots of errors).
Ideally I only ever want this to happen once.  Is there a way to tell docker not to run the scripts if they have already been ran?

I really want to reduce setup of a local db to really one thing:

`docker-compose up` - should do everything.

EDIT:

I tried wrapping the SQL scripts using:

```
if [ ! -d "/var/lib/mssql/data" ]; then 
  # scripts in here
fi
```

but it always skips over them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @Twig2let's [point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106466/99189), the setup.sql is *not* being run in the Dockerfile.  setup.sql is run from configure-db.sh, which is run from entrypoint.sh, which is the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile, which means it runs every time the container starts.

If you want to install the schema during the build stage, you have to execute it with a RUN directive in the Dockerfile somehow.  I suspect you'll find that tricky because you'll probably need to get the server process up and running during the build and then shut it back down.

I suspect you're on a better path with adding your check to see if the initialization has already happened.  You'll just need to make the detection more accurate.  For example, try to find some way to check if `$(MSSQL_DB)` already exists, or modify the sql statements with `IF NOT EXISTS` type logic, if that's supported for all the initialization statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move any "one-time" scripts you need to provision the container into a Dockerfile. They will only get run once during `docker-compose build`. That way `docker-compose` just needs to care about starting and stopping the service.

Comment: Thanks, if you look at the github  the scripts are called from the docker file.

Comment: The ENTRYPOINT is defined in the Dockerfile, which will run entrypoint.sh > configure-db.sh ... each time the container is started. Where have you aded the directory existence check? There's also a section on inheriting from the image which may be useful
https://github.com/mcmoe/mssqldocker#inheriting-from-the-image

Comment: I added the directory check in configure-db.sh.  I wrapped the sqlcmd calls... But I guess the dB will exist at this point...?

Comment: As @Jeremy said, i think you're on the right track with this, try coding more defensively in each of your setup scripts e.g. perform some existence checks. Assuming, for example, one of your scripts is seeding a table, the generic data dir check might prove unreliable.